# Doxygen javadoc-style tag description spanning multiple lines

Tags: documentation, javadoc, doxygen, documentation-generation

In a C++ project I'm using doxygen and the javadoc style for documentation. I'm fairly new to javadoc and am not sure whether this type of thing is valid.

```
/**
 * ...stuff...
 * @return foo foo foo foo foo. Foo foo
 * foo foo foo foo foo.
 */
```

i.e. the information for what is being returned (and my question applies to all tags) needs to  cover multiple lines. Is this automatically detected or do I need to do something special?

Also, from what I understand you can have a short class description and a more in depth class description. Like the problem above, can the short class description be more than one line? If so, what is the syntax for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [doxygen docs](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html) state that

> If {curly} braces are used the
>   argument extends until the next
>   paragraph. Paragraphs are delimited by
>   a blank line or by a section
>   indicator.

The `return` command is listed as a paragraph-style command.  So you can use as many lines as you want, add one extra blank line or just start a new command to end the `return`.